# Looking for clarification on event intersection $\cap$ and how to explain to non statisticians

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem, intersection-theory

I have a few things I am hoping to get clarified.  Let's say we want to determine $Pr(A \cap B)$.

- Can we say $Pr(A \cap B)$ is the joint probability of A and B occurring?  Or is that the wrong term to use?  In calculating conditional probabilities, this seems like it's the correct term to use to describe the numerator.  Assuming A and B are independent, we have $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) * Pr(B)$.  If dependent, we have $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A | B) * Pr(B)$
- However, we also have the formula $Pr(A \cap B) = Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cup B)$.  In this case, would you still describe $Pr(A \cap B)$ as a joint probability?

If you were explaining the above concept to someone completely new at statistics, how would you explain the situation where we have two formulas for $Pr(A \cap B)$?  To be more specific, how would you explain to someone when to use which formula and why there are two formulas?

Comment: To begin, you can note the former only applies to independent events while the latter holds in general and reduces to the former when independence is known or assumed.

Comment: How would $Pr(A) + Pr(B) - Pr(A \cup B)$ ever reduce to $Pr(A) * Pr(B)$?  I don't see how multiplying two numbers will equal a linear combination of values in all cases, even if we assume independence.

Comment: oh right I mistook it for something else (that when rearranging the formula for $P(A\cup B)$, it reduces to $P(A)+P(B)$ when the events are mutually exclusive) terribly sorry for the noise!

Comment: It is always described as joint probability. Explaining when to use which formula is best done with exercises. In practice, $\mathbb{P}[A \cap B] = \mathbb{P}[A]\mathbb{P}[B]$ is more useful because, if you have random sampling assumption, deriving almost any conceivable estimator will rely on this idea.